# Which convention of naming features and data-access is better in Nx monorepo?

Tags: angular, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I'm starting to work with Nx in my new Angular Project and I was wondering how I should start to create new libs in my project.

I can't find answers for my question, so I decided to ask you here.

First:

```
apps/
├── first-app
└── second-ap
libs/
├── first-app/
    └── feature/
        └── orders
             └── src/
                 └── lib/
                      └── first-app-feature-orders.component.ts
        └── tasks
    └── data-access/
        └── orders
        └── tasks
    └── utils/
    └── ui/

└──  second-app/
    └── feature/
        └── products
        └── items
    └── data-access/
        └── products
        └── items
    └── utils/
    └── ui/
```

Or this one?:

```
apps/
├── first-app
└── second-ap
libs/
├── first-app/
    └── feature-orders/
        └── src/
            └── lib/
                 └── first-app-feature-orders.component.ts
    └── feature-tasks
    └── data-access-orders
    └── data-access-tasks
    └── utils/
    └── ui/

└──  second-app/
    └── feature-products/
    └── feature-items/
    └── data-access-products
    └── data-access-items
    └── utils/
    └── ui/
```

I'm expecting someone will explain me how the best way should looks, thanks!